# Filtering a sql count(*) with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, count, sqlalchemy, filtering

How can I do the following SQL query using SQLAlchemy?

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM det_factura
WHERE company = 31
  AND date::text LIKE '2011-05% ';
```

Comment: What SQL backend are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `det_factura` is also a mapped object, then this query should do it:

```
qry = (session.query(func.count(det_factura.id))
        .filter(det_factura.company==31)
        .filter(det_factura.date.like('2010-05%'))
        )
```

If it is a `table` instance, the one below should work:

```
qry = select([func.count(det_factura.id)],
        and_(det_factura.company==31,
             det_factura.date.like('2010-05%')
            )
        )
```

Comment: Thank you. SQLSoup I'm working with, as I adapt this code to sqlsoup.

Comment: hmm.. but what if you don't have an id field? how do you simply get "count(*)", possibly in the presence of other things in select list (so you cant use sqlalchemy .count())?

Comment: @shaunc: You can always do `func.count('*')` to get a `COUNT(*)` SQL expression.